# Unable to select Black & White printing under color mode in Firefox on multiple OS's

Tags: firefox

I've recently switched back to Firefox from Edge and have run into a frustrating issue.

When I try to print documents from Firefox the Color Mode in the print settings is grayed out so I can't select B&W.

This same problem exists both on my MacOS laptop + my Windows 11 desktop. Additionally, they are connected to different printers on different networks. It also occurs whether I'm trying to print a PDF or anything else in Firefox.

Based on this, it appears Firefox is the culprit here.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Firefox Version:** 108.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get an answer from the Firefox support forum and confirm the issue is within Firefox...sharing the answer here for anybody who may run into this issue in the future.

> We don't know of an API to detect the grayscale capability, so we try and set DMCOLOR_MONOCHROME on the printer device/properties and if it accepts it then we assume it should contain B&W option.

> Seems in this case that method didn't accurately reflect what the currently installed driver supported.

> You have to use the system dialog for now.

And below is the workaround:

```
Enter about:config in the URL bar and set print.prefer_system_dialog = true
```